# How to open mounted disk on mac through java program?

Tags: java, macos, mount, dmg

I am downloading a dmg file and then trying to open up the installer automatically through java code.

I am able to download the file and then mount it using "hdiutil attach file.dmg".

> **Download file using URL , Input stream and Output stream**
>
> **Mount dmg by:**
> */usr/bin/hdiutil attach file.dmg*

I am unable to open up this mounted disk so that the installer comes on foreground. Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Thanks!

Harsha P

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().open("... .dmg");` might be an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute `open /Volumes/VolumeName` and it'll open the finder folder for it

or run an applescript using `osascript` to bring the finder to foreground explicitly if needed:

`property the_path : "/Volumes/MyMacDrive/Mani/WorkSpace/"
set the_folder to (POSIX file the_path) as alias
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    if window 1 exists then
        set target of window 1 to the_folder
    else
        reveal the_folder
    end if
end tell`